# pivot with more than 100 pivotItems

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivotitem

I have book reader application and initially we thought using pivot with multiple pivot items which will be easy and will give rich look and feel.

But looks like it has its own limitations? No mater how I load pivot items ( Databinding Vs xml, runtime in code ). It gives out of memory exception if items are more then 100.

Any other alternative to this solution? Is there better control available which can support multiple pages ( 1000 pages atleast)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pivot control design guidelines for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202919%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) says:

> Apps should minimize the number of pivot pages (four pages or fewer).
>   Users can become lost if they jump from pivot page to pivot page. Use
>   Pivot controls sparingly and limit the use of pivot pages to scenarios
>   where it’s appropriate for the experience.

The pivot is not supposed to be used for your problem.
Basically, pivot should not have more that 6-7 pivot item.

You need to use another way, for ex. `LongListSelector` or a `ListBox`

Comment: @jimpanger - Thanks for your reply, But surprise to see such limiations on pivot control. I glanced through LongListSelector but doesn't serve same purpose as I intend to use. (looking for multipage slide )

Comment: If you want to  multipage slide - just detect slide event and changed page content with animation. It is more simple and low performance.

Comment: @jimpanzer Agreed. Perhaps load the next page and cache the previous page on pivot show, so only ever three pages in memory.

Comment: @MichaelItzoe, yes, I mean it.